# Angular: Render externalized strings containing scope variables in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to render externalized strings (passed from server in my case) in the controller?

**My use case**: I'm using angular-toastr as an alert service, and I must pass message and title to the toastr object. The tricky part is when the strings contain scope variables, e.g: `stringFromServer = "Something with {{someVariable}} went wrong"`.

I know in my HTTP callback about the `someVariable` but I want to render it to the string before passing it as a message to the alert service.

Is this possible, and what would be the best way?

Comment: `stringFromServer = "Something with " + $scope.someVariable + " wen't wrong";`

Comment: I don't want to split up stringFromServer, since I wouldn't know where to split without doing a string.indexOf(). I wanted to know if I can somehow call something like: angular.render( stringFromServer, {someVariable: value} ). And also this should be able to handle multiple variables.

Comment: Can you have the variable name written by the server? I don't have time to test it right now but I think $interpolate might be what you're looking for https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: The placeholder is defined in the externalized strings on the server, and rendered within the scope.
$interpolate seems like a good fit, thank you! If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the server can render the string with a $scope.variable placeholder, $interpolate seems like what you're looking for.

Please see [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)