# How to externalize array of string in Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I'm a beginner in Angular. There are so many articles about externalizing the string but none of them answered my doubts. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198050/angular-render-externalized-strings-containing-scope-variables-in-the-controlle) also. My senior has told me to externalize all the strings in my code. Straight forward or hard coded strings I've already externalized but there are two array of strings also. I'll show you my code (*minimal code):

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<h2 [translate]="'timeselection.tshead'"></h2>
```

**assets/i18/en-Us.json**

```
{
    "App": {
        ...
    },
    "Header": {
       ...
    },
    "SubTabLabels": {
        ...
    },
    "Errors": {
        ...
    },
    "timeselection": {
        "tshead": "Time selection"
    }
}
```

This was easy. But in my typescript file there are some arrays. I've been told to externalize them also. Here is the code:

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class TimeselectorComponent {

  ...

  public arr = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

  public source = ['Calendar year', 'Year-to-date', 
  'Fiscal Year-To-Date', 'Fiscal Calendar Year', 'Rolling 12 months'];

  ...
}
```

See I've two arrays here `arr` and `source`. Please help me externalize any one of the two if it is doable.

PS: We are using these two packages `"@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1"` and `"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0"`

Comment: You need to load your *en.json* file and then store it some place(array/local storage). Next you need to search for the desired key from that array/storage.

Comment: What's the concrete problem? An array of strings contains strings. So externalize each of those strings. Are you asking how to use ngx-translate out of a template? Have you read https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#4-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive? Note that `[translate]="'timeselection.tshead'"` can be reduce to the more readable `translate="timeselection.tshead"`

Comment: I believe OP wants to externalize his array in a .ts file

Comment: :-) this raises a whole new set of questions in my mind.

Comment: I want to externalize strings into same json file i showed in the question.

Comment: OK. So use keys rather than values in your code, and use the translate service (I'm assuming you're using ngx-translate) to get the translation of the keys.https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#4-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive, https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods

Comment: @JBNizet. Yes I'm using `ngx-translate` Actually it was already there when i got this project. but i'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: I posted the links to the documentation in my above comment. Read it. ngx-translate has a service you can use to get translations of keys.

Comment: We are using these two packages `"@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1"` and `"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0"`